# Can we refresh a Materialized View using another Materialized View

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, oracle10g, materialized-views

I am using Oracle 10g DB.

I need to create a Materialised view "XXARG_DRAGON" using another Materialized View "XXARG_GOKU".

XXARG_GOKU Materialized view contains 5 different tables combined using joins.

Is it possible to refresh the MV "XXARG_DRAGON" using Fast method with row ID ?

Comment: As with most questions - how are the views defined, have you tried it, what was the outcome ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you execute fast refresh of XXARG_GOKU? If no, then the answer to your question is definitely "No". If yes then the answer is "Maybe".

Comment: Yes I can do fast refresh for XXARG_GOKU and for XXARG_DRAGON i can do fast refresh without using XXARG_GOKU MV.

But I haven't tried combining both for a fast MV Refresh.